# Prove or disprove: MSO can be used to express finite models over an empty signature

Tags: logic

The question is:

There is an MSO sentence ϕ, over the empty signature, such that M⊨ϕ if and only if M has a finite universe?

I think it isn't true because I cannot express the idea of a 1-1 function which is required for the proof (as i see it).

How can I prove it otherwise?

I tried googling without success.

Comment: So the statement is that there is an MSO sentence $\phi$ such that $M\models \phi$ if and only if $M$ has a finite universe?

Comment: @OveAhlman: yes, over the empty signature.

Comment: Question edited.